# actionscript 3 php variables are not changing

Tags: php, variables, actionscript

I am working on a random number generator in PHP and I want to send the result to the AS3 
(it is much complicated but this is the main purpose)

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    function random() {
      calculating it...sql query ...blabla
      return $randomNumber;
    }
    print "randomNumber=".random();
?>
```

**AS3:**

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest("mylink");  
function randomPhp():void {     
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeRandom);
    loader.load( myRequest );
}
function completeRandom(e:Event):void {
   winner=e.target.data.randomNumber;
   loader.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, completeRandom );
}
```

The first time it generates a random Number but after that it's not changing if I call it multiple times. 
It's like if it creates an instance in the cache.I don't know how to fix this or reset it.
And if I run my project and in the time I delete the whole PHP , the AS3 is running like nothing happened.
Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny enough you will have to add a RandomNumber to get your RandomNumber ;) or better a timeStamp to the URLRequest!
Otherwise you will get the cached Request!
Why do you need the random number from php? and not just make it in as3?

```
URLRequest("mylink"+"?"+new Date().getTime());
```

or like i said a `...+"?"+Math.random()*1000);`

Comment: cause I'm building a wheel of fortune app and the percentages are stored in a database and I need PHP to access it and the request was to generate from php so the user cannot write his own winner number.

Comment: THX !!! It works :D but it's not eating my resources that there are a lots of instances ? Is there a method to clean them up?? Or the GC will do that. Cause I'm woried about crushing in long time term.

Comment: The gc will take care of that. Since its the correct answer pls mark it as accepted, thats how this site works.